# Java/Android: Convert Json date String to readable text

Tags: java, android

Hi there I am new to Android Programming:
I received a date String from a JSON web service in the format:

"2013-01-01 00:00:00"

Question: How do I convert it to the following format

January 01 2013

Please help

Comment: a bit of google + SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
  String dtStart = "2013-01-01 00:00:00";  
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM , yyyy",Locale.US);  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
        System.out.println(date);  
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
df.parse(dateString);
```